# I try to use "Responsive Image Gallery" with "jflickrfeed" (How can I load & append ?)

Tags: jquery, gallery, feed, flickr

**jflickrfeed :** http://files.gethifi.com/posts/jflickrfeed/example.html

**Responsive Image Gallery :** http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/

Anyway can I .append html from **jflickrfeed** before **Responsive Image Gallery** script loaded ?

I try :

Before : http://jsfiddle.net/Chhu6/

After : http://jsfiddle.net/Chhu6/1/ <--- It look like **Responsive Image Gallery** cannot read append HTML from **jflickrfeed**

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Chhu6/2/ done by me self :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Chhu6/2

Done !